# How to traverse back to activty with some data from webview in android

Tags: android, webview, transactions

I want to call web view to do a transaction and after -- completing the transaction or if user cancels the transaction -- I want to traverse back to the activity from which web view get called with some data like of success message if transaction was successful or any other message.

Comment: you just can addJavaScriptInterface

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira  how can i do this please give me some code or refer a lint to page.?
How will i get data from javascriptInterface??

Answer (score 0):

addJavaScriptInterface to webview :

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {
        @JavascriptInterface 
      public void performClick()
      {
         //do your activity stuff here
      }
    }, "doClick()");
```

and in your web:

```
<button type="button" onClick="doClick.performClick();">Click Me! </button>
```